# Who has invited a guest user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I want to build a user review application for Azure AD. But unfortunately there is no Azure AD user property that indicates the inviting user.

Is there any way to find out who has invited a guest user?

Comment: I guess it will solve your expectation.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah you can find out who has invited `Guest User` in your tenant. To do this you have two ways:

***1. Azure Portal***

1. Log In to Azure portal
2. Click on Azure Active Directory
3. Under `Monitoring` Click on `Audit logs`

See the screen shot below:

[image]

> Azure portal operation you could refer this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/auditing-and-reporting)

**2. Microsoft Graph API Reference:**

You can also retrieve who has invited `Guest User` in your tenant using `MicrosftGraph` API: See the below steps:

**Request URL:** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/directoryAudits`

**Permission Required:**  `AuditLog.Read.All`

See the screen shot how would you do it in `azure portal`

[image]

Once you add permission then click on *`Grant admin consent for YourTenant`*

**Test On Post Man:**

[image]

You would seen on the picture `initiatedBy` your guest user.

> If you need more information you could refer this official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-auditlog-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#what-can-i-do-with-audit-log-apis-in-microsoft-graph)

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it doesn't work (of course) if they were added longer ago than the audit log retention period - it would be nice if this metadata were retained linked to the user rather than disappearing after 30 / 90 days.