# Event and getting who invited a guest in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We need to develop a governance engine for guests who is invited in Azure AD. Is it possible to get an event via web hook or others where we can catch when a user is invited, and who invited the guest? Graph API or other frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not any document that create an event when guest is added and who added. But For Workaround you can use this Microsoft Document to get the List of Guest User and when they added and who is issuer (Added by whom)

```
Graph Api : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType  eq 'guest'
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This only provides the domain but not the user who created the object?

Comment: You can refer this thread to get the who has invited the guest user : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56765591/who-has-invited-a-guest-user

Comment: Appreciated, thanks.